# Unable to decrypt AES-256 cipher text

Tags: java, encryption, bouncycastle

I get this error:

```
org.bouncycastle.crypto.InvalidCipherTextException: pad block corrupted
    at org.bouncycastle.crypto.paddings.PKCS7Padding.padCount(Unknown Source)
    at org.bouncycastle.crypto.paddings.PaddedBufferedBlockCipher.doFinal(Unknown Source)
```

Here is my code:

```
public byte[] process(byte[] input, BufferedBlockCipher bufferedBlockCipher, CipherParameters cipherParameters, boolean forEncryption) throws InvalidCipherTextException {
    bufferedBlockCipher.init(forEncryption, cipherParameters);
    int inputOffset = 0;
    int inputLength = input.length;
    int maximumOutputLength = bufferedBlockCipher.getOutputSize(inputLength);
    byte[] output = new byte[maximumOutputLength];
    int outputOffset = 0;
    int outputLength = 0;
    int bytesProcessed;
    bytesProcessed = bufferedBlockCipher.processBytes(
            input, inputOffset, inputLength,
            output, outputOffset
        );
    outputOffset += bytesProcessed;
    outputLength += bytesProcessed;
    bytesProcessed = bufferedBlockCipher.doFinal(output, outputOffset);
    outputOffset += bytesProcessed;
    outputLength += bytesProcessed;

    if (outputLength == output.length) {
        return output;
    } else {
        byte[] truncatedOutput = new byte[outputLength];
        System.arraycopy(
                output, 0,
                truncatedOutput, 0,
                outputLength
            );
        return truncatedOutput;
    }
}
```

Comment: Although in principle padding error can be caused by a bug in the sender, 99.99% of the time it is because your key, IV and/or ciphertext is wrong or altered somehow, or you have the wrong mode or padding. You don't say or show anything about how these were handled so it's impossible to give any useful advice about them. FYI `java.util.Arrays.copyOf(byte[],int)` is a simpler replacement for your last 2-3 statements.

Comment: public byte[] decryptAES256(byte[] input, byte[] key) throws InvalidCipherTextException {
     assert key.length == 32; // 32 bytes == 256 bits
     CipherParameters cipherParameters = new KeyParameter(key);
     BlockCipher blockCipher = new AESEngine();
     BlockCipherPadding blockCipherPadding = new PKCS7Padding();
     BufferedBlockCipher bufferedBlockCipher = new PaddedBufferedBlockCipher(blockCipher, blockCipherPadding);
     return decrypt(input, bufferedBlockCipher, cipherParameters);
 } Does it clarify the question? I am using PKCS7Padding for both encryption and decryption

Comment: Please don't put code in comments, it's unreadable. And please don't put your question in comments, Stack policy is to have the question in the question.

Answer (score 0):

The output is normally padded and longer than the input. You should not truncate the output.

Comment: I've removed that code used for truncate but still I am getting same exception. One more problem I've found that is I am getting this exception on       doFinal(output, outputOffset); this line. My decryption is working fine for less the 16 characters with same code but not working with more than 16.

Comment: Q doesn't specify mode but since it clearly uses pkcs7 padding the ciphertext is longer than the plaintext, and for decryption the ciphertext is the input and the plaintext is the output so the output is shorter, and the `outputLength` computed from the return values of `processBytes` and `doFinal` _is_ the correct length (if the calls were successful).